# Top CPU usage process in Bash prompt

Tags: bash, prompt

I am facing the following problem when I try to display top cpu process in my Bash prompt : the info I get is so *dynamic* that I cannot have significant result.
I explain : I grab a string from **top** command, to get the PID, Command and CPU% of process at top of usage at this instant. This is stored in **`$topcpuS`** variable.

Then I want to know the length of this string (like `${#topcpuS}`), to adjust my display in prompt.
**Problem** : between the moment I capture the string, and the moment I want to get its length, the content has already changed - so the length is not matching the actual content of `$topcpuS`...

Evidence is shown when I display `$topcpuS` twice in PS1 : contents differ.

I guess I am doing something wrong.

Abstract of my Bash script (call to script :   `source /path/to/myscript ; ps1_test`) :

```
ps1_test() {
  ## Function used to get string length, by ignoring escape sequence
  ## for ANSI color or UNICODE special characters
  ## Usage :   count_char "$my_string"
  count_char() {
      local xcc=$(echo "$1" | sed -r 's/((\\\\\[)?\\[eE]\[[0-9]*(;[0-9]*)*(m|f)(\\\\\])?|\\u1F6(0|1|3)|\\u[0-9a-fA-F]{3}|\\xf0\\x9f\\x98\\x(8|9|b)|(\\x[0-9a-fA-F]{2}){2}\\x[0-9a-fA-F])//g')
      printf '%u' ${#xcc}
  }  ## END count_char

  ## Get top process
  local topcpuS=" \$(top -bn1 | tail -n +8 | sort -nrk 9 | awk 'NR==6 {printf(\"[%s]%s:%s%\",\$1,\$12,\$9)}') "
  ## Get length of topcpuS
  local topcpuL="\$(count_char \"$topcpuS\")"
  ## DISPLAY PROMPT (with topcpuS called twice...)
  PS1="\n$TOP >${topcpuS}< [Length:${topcpuL}]\n$TOP >${topcpuS}< [Length:${topcpuL}]\n\\$"
}
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: `ps aux | sort -r -k 3 | head -n 5` ?

Comment: Or use `ps -e  -opcpu=,cmd= | sort -r -k1 | sed -n 's/ *[^ ]* *//p;q'`

Comment: Hi, thx. I dont want to use PS, because you dont have a snapshot of "instant" CPU usage. Instead, PS gives you an overall CPU usage for a process... Quite interesting too, but not what I am expecting.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need one function to output everything - both the top output and the things depending on the length.

```
ps1_test() {
  ## Function used to get string length, by ignoring escape sequence
  ## for ANSI color or UNICODE special characters
  ## Usage :   count_char "$my_string"
  count_char() {
      local xcc=$(echo "$1" | sed -r 's/((\\\\\[)?\\[eE]\[[0-9]*(;[0-9]*)*(m|f)(\\\\\])?|\\u1F6(0|1|3)|\\u[0-9a-fA-F]{3}|\\xf0\\x9f\\x98\\x(8|9|b)|(\\x[0-9a-fA-F]{2}){2}\\x[0-9a-fA-F])//g')
      printf '%u' ${#xcc}
  }  ## END count_char

  top_stuff() {
        local topcpuS=$(top -bn1 | tail -n +8 | sort -nrk 9 | awk 'NR==6 {printf("[%s]%s:%s%",$1,$12,$9)}')
        local topcpuL=$(count_char "$topcpuS")
        echo ">${topcpuS}< [Length:${topcpuL}]"
  }

  ## DISPLAY PROMPT (with topcpuS called twice...)
  PS1="\n$TOP \$(top_stuff)\n$TOP \$(top_stuff)\n\\$"
}
```

This will call the `top_stuff` twice, but each length will be correct.

Comment: Indeed this solves the issue for length. With 2 calls of top_stuff you have 2 different results. But at least, the length is correct.